# Making calculator app in React. setState is not working

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm making a calculator app in React. Here I have App component and Button component. When I click a button, despite I setState with parameter (event.target.getAttribute('data-number'), it console logs different number from the button's attribute.

When I click button with 'data-number=1', state 'result' is set to "0". Then I click button with 'data-number=7', state 'result' is set to '1'. I wonder what is happening and how to fix this problem.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { result: 0 };

    currentNumber = (number) => {
        this.setState({ result: number })
        console.log("Number from Button", number); // 1
        console.log("Current number in state", this.state.result); // 0
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick = {this.currentNumber} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
class Button extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li><button data-number="1" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>1</button></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just cut the rest of my code in Button component. It should be <li><button data-number="1" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>1</button></li>, <li><button data-number="2" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>2</button></li>, ... <li><button data-number="7" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>7</button></li>

Comment: can you add that code into the body of your question for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `setState` is async, meaning state is not updated right away. You can pass a callback that gets run after state updates:

```
this.setState({ result: number }, () => {
        console.log("Number from Button", number); // 1
        console.log("Current number in state", this.state.result); // 1
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I'll read the document more..

Answer (score 0):

As @Smarticles101 mentioned, `setState` is async. Here's your code working properly.

Notice the difference between the callback logs and the outside callback logs. Checkout these [docs on setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more information.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { result: 0 };

    currentNumber = (number) => {
        this.setState({ result: number }, () => {
          console.log("Callback, number: ", number);
          console.log("Callback, result: ", this.state.result);
        })
        
        console.log("Outside callback, number: ", number);
        console.log("Outside callback, result: ", this.state.result);
        
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.currentNumber} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Button extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
            <li><button data-number="1" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>1</button></li>,
            <li><button data-number="2" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>2</button></li>, ...
            <li><button data-number="7" onClick={event => this.props.onClick(event.target.getAttribute('data-number'))}>7</button></li>
            </ul>
            )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render((<App/>), document.getElementById('testing'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand the async part but I'll search more..